# jQuery Mobile, transitions flicker when using Fast buttons and changePage

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I have some issues with Jquery mobile when running on my (Android 2.3) Galaxy SII.
Basically to avoid flickering when changing pages, I added this into my css :

```
 .ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

It works fine. No flicker...
In order to eliminate the delay when clicking on links I used Google Fast Button implementaition, and the flicker effect is back again.

```
function initFastButtons() {
    new FastButton(document.getElementById("goFastTest"), goSomewhere);
}
```

In the html body :

```
<a href="#testId" id="goFastTest">test</a>
```

```
function goSomeWhere() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#pageTest", { transition: "slide"} );
}
```

Have you experienced this behavior?
How can I get rid of this flickering effect, keep the transition smooth and still have the Fast Button working correctly?

Comment: I guess it is not possible to have both? Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I see the same thing happening (also in jqm-1.1 and current master at git). I suspect a difference in #page-based clicks and programmatically changing pages, but I'm still figuring it out...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16692917/104746 --- Set viewport to user-scalable=no solved the problem for me.