# Jquery mobile list content remains when going to another list

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a mobile app using phonegap and using JQM, jqm. That has a number of pages, each page has a listview, and the list content is dynamically loaded from a server, the list may has 30 items or more

When I test the app using android 4.3, I have a problem with the list, which is when I am in a page that has a list, and go to another one that has another list, its content is loaded perfectly but, when I scroll down fast, I can see remains of the previous page list fading out, this happen only when I do the scroll down the first time.

I tried to use a separate page for each page instead of single-page template, but the problem is still. I couldn't find any similar problem.

This image shows an example of the problem:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps specifically target the previous list and set `display:none` in the CSS

Comment: sorry shouldn't previous page with all its content be hidden, if I go to another?

Comment: Yes, perhaps it is interfering with the transition animations.  Since you say it is fading out.  Perhaps you need to specify animation-transition as none.  `data-transition="none"` in the link which loads the 2nd list.

Comment: I am actually not using any transition, have set all data-transition to "none" to speed up the app, maybe I use the wrong word "fade" but the bottom old list items show like been erased and new drawn above them.

Comment: Check that you have done as suggested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723514/blinking-flickering-with-jqm-and-phonegap-on-android

Comment: Yes, I came across this question and  have done some of the solutions like  while other already modified in JQM 1.4 I am using, it solve flickering when transmit to another page but not solving content overlapping. Thank you for trying to help.