# PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile Annoying Blink Between Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I hope you are ok.

So, the thing is, I'm writing a PhoneGap app using jQuery Mobile.

The jQuery Mobile version is: jquery.mobile-1.4.0.

I'm using several ways to do transitions between the views that are located inside the same file, not on separate html files, like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="preload">

<div data-role="page" id="noConnection">

<div data-role="page" id="intro">
```

... and so.

The current viewport meta tag is this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

So far, I have not been able to remove that blink between transitions.

About the methods to change between views, I have tried several ways but in all of them I get the same blink:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#termsAndConditions", {transition: "slide", reverse: false});

$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#termsAndConditions", {transition: "flow", reload: true});
```

Do you have any sugestion about how could I solve this?

It happens in iPhone with iOS 7, iPad with iOS 7, not tested yet in Android.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723514/blinking-flickering-with-jqm-and-phonegap-on-android

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the idea but is not working. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Have you tried the CSS regarding webkit-backface-visibility?

Comment: I tryied this:

ui-page {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

... with a negative result...

Comment: Hopefully it was a typo in your comment but it should be `.ui-page` with a dot (.) infront of ui-page

Comment: Hey Rob, the css rule is bad, I had it without the dot, so, I will try like this and will let you know. Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

use overlay, not hidden when transitioning

```
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-page {
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
```